# Estado de react elimina propiedades despues de actualizar el estado

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

Tengo la siguiente función que un botón activa:

```javascript
function handleRemoveItem(index) {
    const items = [...form[itemName]]
    items.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(items)
    //setForm({ ...form, [itemName]: items })
}
```

La constante `items` se ve así cuando se activa la función:

```javascript
[
    0: {id: 8, productName: 'Producto 1', stock: 20, expiration: '2025-07-01', lab: 2}
    1: {id: 2, productName: 'Producto 2', stock: 7, expiration: '2024-08-01', lab: 3}
    2: {id: 15, productName: 'Producto 3', stock: 4, expiration: '2024-09-01', lab: 2}
]
```

Cada objeto tiene un atributo `id`. La función se utiliza para eliminar un objeto de ese array y funciona perfectamente bien cuando la cuarta línea está comentada, pero necesito que el estado de React se actualice para trabajar con él.

Entonces, aquí está el problema:
Cuando la cuarta línea está comentada, los objetos se ven así (asumiendo que el parámetro `index` es 1):

```javascript
[
    0: {id: 8, productName: 'Producto 1', stock: 20, expiration: '2025-07-01', lab: 2}
    1: {id: 15, productName: 'Producto 3', stock: 4, expiration: '2024-09-01', lab: 2}
]
```

Todo bien, cada objeto permanece intacto, pero cuando descomento esa línea (para que se actualice el estado), se ve así:

```javascript
[
    0: {id: 8, productName: 'Producto 1', stock: 20, expiration: '2025-07-01', lab: 2}
    1: {productName: 'Producto 3', stock: 4, expiration: '2024-09-01', lab: 2}
]
```

El `id` del segundo objeto desaparece, y no sé por qué, porque el código sigue siendo el mismo, solo que con esa línea descomentada. La consola lo muestra antes de que se actualice el estado y me arroja ese array. Lo extraño es que solo afecta a los objetos siguientes. Por ejemplo, si elimino el primer objeto, desaparece el atributo `id` para los siguientes 2, pero si elimino el último objeto, los primeros 2 permanecen intactos.

He intentado muchas cosas, incluso pregunté a ChatGPT qué está pasando. Intenté usar `.map()` en lugar de `.splice()`, pero nada funciona, ni siquiera con `.filter()` o `.slice()`. Incluso intenté tomar todos los `id` y volver a ponerlos juntos y nada funciona.

No sé qué estoy pasando por alto, tal vez sea algo en React que no comprendo, intente ver lo que pasa al rededor de la funcion cuando la llamo a ver si algo mas esta actualizando el estado, pero de todas las funciones que tengo en el `customHook` esta es la unica que da problemas ¿Alguna idea?